# What am I going to do with an iMac 27 inch's display 3, 4 years from now?

Tags: imac, display

I want to buy a 27 inch iMac, but the monitor cannot be re-used... it cannot be hooked up to any KVM (Keyboard / Video / Mouse) switch to be used with a PC too...

Also, 3, 4 years down the road, I know the iMac will become slow and probably need to buy another computer.  At that time, what am I going to do with the monitor?  Apple is saying they save the "microwatt" between your typing, but what about wasting a good monitor like that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The display port on the latest iMac's (actually since late 2009) acts as both an output (for an external display) or an input (to make the imac screen a monitor).

See http://smokingapples.com/asides/new-27-imac-doubles-up-as-external-monitor/

Comment: +1 Wow, that's news to me! Beats my answer by a mile. :-)

Comment: actually, by 2 miles =)

Comment: Sigh, this is apparently not true anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Sell it. Used Macs hold their resale value better, in my experience, than used PCs do. (Also, keep the original box & other packaging - that will help the resale value.)

Comment: that's quite nice a display... I was hoping to be able to re-use it.  also, selling it... may fetch you $600?  it will be a computer with such a nice display but with the processor that nobody wants to use